# Database for US Universities and Colleges

Tags: database

Not sure if this is the proper place to post this question, but I've seen questions regarding ISBN databases, so I thought it would be appropriate.

In my website, I intend allow my users to choose between all the US college/universities (community or 4 year institutes). I would then store their selection in a database.

At first I thought about allowing them to input the name themselves, but saw some issues with that. I tried to look for a database of some sort, but all I found were search engines to find a specific university.

I was hoping to find a database can I export to my own database (SQL Server) and have users search my own database.

Has anyone come across this issue and found a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is an old question, but I wanted to post the answer for those who find this page.

This should do the trick: http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/GetDownloadFile.aspx

It's a csv and xls file of all the accredited universities in the US. It's about 22,800 rows and narrowing it uniquely by name brings it down to about 9,000.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is a wonderful resource.  I know the question is only asking for US universities, but I would like to add for those looking for it a nice collection of world universities, collected by akeda on github:  https://github.com/gedex/World-University-Names-Database

Comment: For anyone using the ope.ed.gov source, a spinner may show up in your browser tab for over a minute or two before the file downloads. Be patient with it.

Comment: For future googlers: https://github.com/lassana/webometrics-parser/

Answer (score 5):

This question was posted in 2011, but luckily data is getting easier to come by!

[Department of Education now has an API](http://www.ed.gov/developer) (also CSV) available to get a variety of data about universities as well as public elementary and high schools.

Their Directory Listing CSV under 'Colleges and Universities' contains about 7,700 rows which matches up pretty well with [NCES data](http://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=84) (from 2012) putting the number of post-secondary institutions in the US around 7,000.

Disclaimer before you go write academic research with that database: Considering that NCES number is a couple years out of date, it seems reasonable to assume this Dept of Ed listing is reasonably accurate though I havent tested it rigorously

Answer (score 2):

You can combine these two by having a search box with auto complete, if the input query does not match, indicate if they want to add this into database. You can create a table in database to hold all these contributions and they won't get added to the list before you or someone approve it.

Answer (score 1):

googling for 'list of us universities' gives me a lot of hits.
you could have a textbox which allows them to enter the name themselves but offers autocomplete functionality which aids them in inputing a string which is an exact match to one in your database (sort of like how facebook autocompletes the friend search on the top right)
if the user ignores this and specifies an unknown string, you could either add this new string to your database or refuse, saying that they should ask the admin to add it for them and then try again

Answer (score 1):

The most complete resource is the IPEDS, you need to click on download survey, and download the year data you like. I have called them to see if they have an API, but no luck there, so it's all in excel format. bummer....

http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the free database of the major worldwide universities:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

It's 9498 Universities from all over the world.

- Their names are translated into 3 languages: English, Russian, Azerbaijani.
- 3072 of them have logos.
- organized by countries

Answer (score 0):

you get complete list from

http://www.webometrics.info/

complete world univerity names and ranks.  now just scrap them .